# How should I design/structure my database and ActiveRecord associations? has_many :through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, database-design, associations

Using Rails 4 (and Postgres), I'm trying to work out the best way in which to structure my ActiveRecord associations and corresponding database tables/relationships for a diet tracking app.

I want my app to be structured as follows:
I have `Document` and `FoodEntry` models. Each `Document` has a number of `FoodEntries`. I want to be able to iterate over them like `document.food_entries.each ...` (which is easy with your typical `has_many` association).

However all the `FoodEntries` for each `Document` need to be able (potentially but not necessarily) to be subdivided by **day**, as this is a natural division for which logic and calculations must be able to be performed, in addition to doing them for the whole document. For instance I'd be using something like `document.day(1).food_entries.each ...`.

Furthermore, each day should be able to be subdivided (again, optionally) into **meals** in a similar manner, e.g. `document.day(1).meal(1).food_entries.each ...`

Lastly, there must be a way to record the user-specified order that the `FoodEntries`, meals, and days are in for each document. Presumably using number sequence(s)?

I was thinking there are a few ways I could do this:

1. **Use a simple `has_many` relationship.** Have `day`, `meal` and `sort` columns in the `food_entries` table, where the value for `day` and `meal` is left blank or given a default value if a day/meal isn't provided. Use a logic-based approach to get and sort the entries for a day or meal.

   Outline:

   ```
   class Document
     has_many :food_entries

   class FoodEntry
     belongs_to :document
   ```

   Potential issues:

   - This might leave things a bit messy in general in the table?
   - All the logic for subdividing things would have to be hand-coded.
   - Storing/using the user-defined (i.e. arbitrary) sort order might get a bit complicated? The order for entries AND days AND meals would have to stored in and inferred from one sequence (unless more columns were added).
2. **Use `has_many :through` to set up associations through `days` and `meals` (naming?) tables.** Entries where a day/meal isn't specified get given a default. Both these tables have their own individual `sort` column, along with the `food_entries` table.

   Outline:

   ```
   class Document
     has_many :days
     has_many :meals, through: :days
     has_many :food_entries, through: :days (AND :meals???)

   class Day
     belongs_to :document
     has_many :meals
     has_many :food_entries, through: :meals

   class Meal
     belongs_to :day
     has_many :food_entries

   class FoodEntry
     belongs_to :meal
   ```

   Potential issues:

   - Adds unnecessary relational complexity? (consider that days or at the very least meals are meant to be optional)
   - Can I even use `has_many :food_entries through: ...` in my `Document` model if it would have to go through both tables?
3. A compromise between the two approaches above: have a `days` table but keep `meal` in a column in the `food_entries` table.
4. Something else? Polymorphic association(s)?

This is getting a bit complicated to wrap my head around, and so I'm really having a hard time working out what I should use. **What is the correct way to go about things?**

---

A couple of final questions which are related but completely optional:

- Ideally the `day` value could be either a `datetime` value or an arbitrary string, depending on what the user sets. Is this possible?
- Could anyone point me to a resource that can inform me about sorting/ordering strategies? Like I said I assume the simplest way is to use a sequence of numbers, but I'm not exactly sure how I would work with such a sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing my #2 option. This has given me the most flexibility and worked out well. I think it has been the most elegant approach for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

**has_many :through**

You'd only use a [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) relationship if you wanted to attribute multiple `FoodEntries` to `Document`, like this:

```
#app/models/document.rb
Class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :food_entries_types
    has_many :food_entries, through: :food_entries_types
end

#app/models/food_entry_type.rb
Class FoodEntryType < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :document
    belongs_to :food_entry
end

#app/models/food_entry.rb
Class FoodEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :food_entries_types
    has_many :documents, through: :food_entries_types
end
```

This would only allow you to associate many `food_entries` with a similar number of `documents`. Although you could add specific `days` & `meals` attributes to the join model, allowing you to call them as required

---

**Scopes**

I believe a much better option for you is to use ActiveRecord [`scopes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes):

```
#app/models/document.rb
Class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :food_entries

    #uses [wday][3]
    #needs to return dates for specific day
    scope :day, ->(day = 1) { where(created_at: Date::DAYNAMES[day]) }
    scope :meal, ->(meal = 1) { where(meal: meal) }
end
```

Because scopes can be chained, I believe you'd be able to do this:

```
food = Document.day(1).meal(2).food_entries
```

---

**Class Method**

You could also create a [`class_method`](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) to achieve something similar:

```
#app/models/document.rb
Class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :food_entries

    def self.sorted(day = 1, meal = 1)
        document = self.where("created_at = ? AND meal = ?", Date::DAYNAMES[day], meal)
    end
end

#app/controllers/documents_controller.rb
def show
    @document = Document.sorted
end
```

Comment: I'm aware of the typical use of `has_many :through` to set up a many-to-many association between two models through a join table. However the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) on the subject also states:
`The has_many :through association is also useful for setting up "shortcuts" through nested has_many associations.`
and gives an example which looks very much like my use case (except with one less model). Could you clarify why scopes would be better?

Comment: See also: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Nested+Associations ("Nested Associations")